# Como Obtener el valor por fracción de hora [Python]

Tags: python

Estoy realizando este código y no se como podría realizar la parte del coste por fracción.
Enunciado: El centro de navegación genera un archivo a partir de las 08:00 y hasta las 18:00 de ese mismo día, posteriormente dicho archivo se emplea para cuadrar la caja al cierre de actividades. La tarifa de cobro de alquiler es la siguiente: por cada hora cumplida $500 y por cada fracción de 15 minutos $100.

Ya he realizado la diferencia de horas y minutos y el coste por hora, lo que necesito es aplicar el monto por fracción de hora cada 15 minutos.

El contenido del archivo es el siguiente.
Número de Máquina, nombre, hora de llegada, minuto de llegada, hora de ida y minuto de ida

```
1,Jose,9,33,10,42
3,Miguel,10,12,12,44
2,Teresa,11,44,14,22
1,Pablo,12,56,15,49
1,Juan,15,55,16,2
2,Jesus,14,41,17,6
3,Maria,14,52,16,12
1,Ana,16,13,18,0
3,Marta,16,36,18,0
```

Este es el codigo que llevo:

```
print("\n   Maquina  Usuario     Tiempo    Monto" )
archivo = open("Ciber.txt")
for reg in archivo:
    valores = reg.split(",")
    maq=int(valores[0])
    nomb=str(valores[1])
    hlleg=int(valores[2])
    mlleg=int(valores[3])
    hid=int(valores[4])
    mid=int(valores[5])

    print("     {0:2}      {1:9}".format(maq,nomb))
    
    consh = hid - hlleg
    consm = mid - mlleg

    if consm <0:
        consm= consm + 60
        consh = consh - 1
    
    if consh >= 1:
        const= cost*consh
```

La salida de los datos debe ser la siguiente :
Nr de máquina Nombre Horas y minutos transcurridos y total de consumo

Comment: sería bueno que indicaras cuál debería ser la salida para el ejemplo que has dado. Esto es, dar un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Primero calculamos la diferencia entre las dos horas:

```
def diff(hi, mi, hf, mf):
    """
    Calcular la diferencia entre dos horas separadas por no más de 24 horas.

    @param hi: Hora inicial
    @param mi: Minuto inicial
    @param hf: Hora final
    @param mf: Minuto final
    @return: Horas, minutos de diferencia
    """
    minutos = (hf - hi) * 60 + (mf - mi)
    if minutos < 0:
        minutos += 24 * 60

    return minutos // 60, minutos % 60
```

Lo que hacemos es convertir las HH:MM a minutos desde la media noche, y luego restar ambas cifras. Si la hora de inicio es más tarde que la hora de termino, le agregamos 24 horas para ajustar.

El resultado está expresado en horas y minutos. Teniendo los minutos, puedes calcular la fracción:

**Demostración**

```
tests = [[1,"Jose",9,33,10,42],
[3,"Miguel",10,12,12,44],
[2,"Teresa",11,44,14,22],
[1,"Pablo",12,56,15,49],
[1,"Juan",15,55,16,2],
[2,"Jesus",14,41,17,6],
[3,"Maria",14,52,16,12],
[1,"Ana",16,13,18,0],
[3,"Marta",16,36,18,0]]

for test in tests:
    maq, user, hi, mi, hf, mf = test
    h, m = diff(hi, mi, hf, mf)
    print(f"{maq} {user}:  {h} horas, {m} minutos")
```

produce

```
1 Jose:  1 horas, 9 minutos
3 Miguel:  2 horas, 32 minutos
2 Teresa:  2 horas, 38 minutos
1 Pablo:  2 horas, 53 minutos
1 Juan:  0 horas, 7 minutos
2 Jesus:  2 horas, 25 minutos
3 Maria:  1 horas, 20 minutos
1 Ana:  1 horas, 47 minutos
3 Marta:  1 horas, 24 minutos
```